# Difference between PageSize and MaxTop

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata, odata-v4

What's the difference between `[EnableQuery(PageSize=20)]` and `[EnableQuery(MaxTop=20)]`?

As far as I can tell they both set a max limit on the result.

Calling `GET odata/Products?$top=100` on either of them both give me only 20 results.

Comment: Try modifying your request to `GET odata/Products` and you will instantly figure out the difference.

Answer (score 5):

### The difference is on Server Pagging Driven Mode

OData provide two modes of server-pagging: **client-driven** and **server-driven**.

`PageSize` controls the page size that server use in server-driven mode. Not used if the caller provide `$top` parameter.

`MaxTop` controls the max `$top` value that caller can specify in client-driven mode.

### Client-driven mode

The caller will provide the page size parameter (`$top`). The server will use the `$top` to make pagging. The caller may provide `$skip` parameter to get next page.

Example:

First Page: `http://server/odata/Entity?$top=20`

Next Page: `http://server/odata/Entity?$top=20&$skip=20`

### Server-driven mode

The caller will not provide page size parameter (`$top`). The server will use `PageSize` parameter to make pagging. Reponse includes a `@data.nextLink` entry in JSON result to caller get the next page data.

Example with `PageSize = 20`:

First Page: `http://server/odata/Entity`

Server will return a `@data.nextLink` to the next page: `http://server/odata/Entity?$skip=20`

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer of @jvitor83 makes sense.

MaxTop only impacts the scenarios in which the request Uri contains $top. If the $top value exceeds the MaxTop value, you may get the following error message:

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. The limit of '20' for Top query has been exceeded. The value from the incoming request is
'100'."
  }
}
```

However, PageSize impacts the final query result. For example, you set `[EnableQuery(PageSize=20)]`, it means you want the server to return 20 results if the number of final result exceeds 20.

And the final query result is decided by whether $top is used. If not $top set, the final query result is the total data set. And, If `$top=x` set and the `x` less than or equal to MaxTop, the final result is the top `x`.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.enablequeryattribute):

MaxTop = Gets or sets the max value of $top that a client can request.

PageSize = Gets or sets the maximum number of query results to send back to clients.

Comment: That doesn't really explain the difference :/